# Position relative to background image

Tags: html, css

Recently im finally making my webgame responsive and im struggling with it.
I researched that in order to my divs to be a proper size on every device I need to set position: relative on parent element, position: absolute on the divs I want to be responsive, and that part I get.

However, I need my divs to be related to the background image, because the parts of the backgrounds are clickable via divs. Can anyone guide me how to do this? Recently Ive got it looking like that:
[image]

I believe I could achieve what I want with setting proper properties on the background image which I currently have set as:

```
#corridor {
/*position: relative;*/
height: 100vh;
width: 85%;
float:right;
background: url("corridor.jpg");
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Provide the fiddle .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/houass4m/  Looks like a mess though without being responsive, thats what im trying to fix now.

Comment: In the fiddle there are 4 *empty* `div`s which, I suppose, you want to position relative to background image. But unless you explain what those `div`s are and where are they supposed to be placed, people won't understand it. Currently couple of them are off by 100s of pixels (horizontally as well as vertically) from the background image.

Comment: Yes, those divs are normally transparent and are placed over doors on the right. When clicked on the div(door) the new element of the page are loaded and you enter the room you clicked.
I guess I could set background-size to "cover" but then im not sure that it wouldnt hurt other levels of the game when I did that, because I have no guarantee that important part of the image wont be cut during resize.